# Freemarker template loading

Tags: java, freemarker

In my application, all freemarker templates  are in /templates/ftl/ so during the application deployment I load a class I call one class that extends FreemarkerManager and has a method

```
Configuration configuration = super.createConfiguration(servletContext);
configuration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/templates/ftl/"));
```

In this way, when I need to load a template file, I can simply do it like this:

```
    ServletContext servletContext = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
    Configuration configFreemarker = (Configuration) servletContext
                    .getAttribute("freemarker.Configuration");
    Template template = configFreemarker.getTemplate("pathToMyTemplate");
```

In only one specific situation, I need to get a template that comes from completely different path (not the /templates/ftl/).

How can I in this specific moment declare 2nd directory for template loading without breaking all the existing code that were calling the old path? Can I have 2 different starting point for template loading at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe just create separate (or temporary) Configuration without specific directory?

Comment: I dont see how is possible to instantiate 2 Configurations since my class needs to extends FreemarkerManager and there i Need to extend method createConfiguration which I already did for the 1st time. Inside I get the Configuration conf = super.createConfiguration(servletContext); but I dont see how can I get the 2nd configuration for the same servletContext

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `MultipleTemplateLoader`.

```
import freemarker.cache.*; // template loaders live in this package

...

FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("/tmp/templates"));
FileTemplateLoader ftl2 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("/usr/data/templates"));
ClassTemplateLoader ctl = new ClassTemplateLoader(getClass(), "");
TemplateLoader[] loaders = new TemplateLoader[] { ftl1, ftl2, ctl };
MultiTemplateLoader mtl = new MultiTemplateLoader(loaders);

cfg.setTemplateLoader(mtl);
```

Source: [Freemarker Manual](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#autoid_41)

Answer (score 0):

Another and a more elegant way (in my opinion) of doing this is within the config xml:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  <property name="templateLoaderPaths">
        <value>/path1/ , /path2/</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```